# Class template with internal functions behaving differently for different input

Tags: c++

Take the following class:

```
template <class T>
class Foo
{
private:
  T x;
public:
  Foo(T y) { x = y; }
  T bar();
};
```

Say I initialized `Foo()` with `int`, or with `double` type object. I would like `bar()` to behave differently for those two types. I guess the easy workaround is to let `bar()` call another template function that reacts to types of `x`, but maybe there is another generic way to do with without defining nested functions..?

**Notice:** I do *not* want `bar()` to take `x` as an argument, I want `x` to stay private and just be callable by `bar()`.

Comment: You can use template specialization for your class and implement `bar()` differently for different `T`.

Comment: @yeputons probably this is what I want - how to do this..?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be

```
#include <type_traits>

template <class T>
class Foo
{
private:
T x;
public:
Foo(T y) { x = y; }
T bar() {
    if(std::is_same<T, int>::value) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 0.0;
    }
}
};
```

There are more ways to do it. You can specialise the class for example.

Hint: If you dont want to check for int and double, but for integer types and floating point typs, there are traits for that too.